# Is possible have to different menu in Action Bar? (Kotlin)

Tags: android

I have an app, which have an action menu item on the right (2). 
I need an ulterior menu in the left(1) or a button in the action bar, is that possible?

I attach a image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yal5I.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may create a custom toolbar. The standard height of a toolbar is `89dp`.
To create a custom toolbar you should make your activity view container `RelativeLayout`. Then create a custom toolbar view (it may also be `RelativeLayout`) which height is `89dp`. Then add your toolbar to the main container and set `alignParentTop` to `true`. So you have a custom flexible toolbar and you can add any view to it. 
This way is very comfortable to use any custom views on your toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same situation of customizing action bar. After a lot of searching I got the solution which is Toolbar.
Checkout: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up
I think from now on, you should start using Toolbar as the default action bar for your apps. It provides high level of customization and material design features.